# How to associate forums & forum posts with the menu structure in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, forum, forums, organic-groups

I've created a members area using organic groups.
This group has a submenu using the menu block module which displays a link to my private forum

How can I get the forum topics to be linked into the menu structure so that when I click into a forum post the submenu stays there. (It dissapears because the forum post isn't in the menu tree)

I could do achieve this by setting a menu link and adding 'forum' as the parent each time, but this is not a suitable solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe module Reference with autocomplet or select forum topic? But this is not clean solution